# Multiple lines in a Coffeescript function

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following Coffeescript:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                $('#target').html(data)
        )
        return false
```

And it translates to this:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#new_event').submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      return $('#target').html(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

So far so good. However, how do I add another line into the submit? For example:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_event').submit ->
        test = $(this).serialize()
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action')
            $(this).serialize()
            (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                $('#target').html(data)
        )
        return false
```

This gives unexpected INDENT error. Can't figure out what I'm missing here...

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you mixed spaces and tabs for indentation. Coffeescript does not like that.

And, by the way, you can write `@` instead of `this`.

Comment: The error is on the `test = ...` line. What should be in front of that line? Spaces or tabs?

Comment: It needs to be indented the same way as the next line (which is supposed to be on the same level). Most people would tell you not to use tabs at all to avoid confusion.

Comment: You're right - the `test...` line is preceded by tabs, and the next line has spaces in front. I'm using Textmate and was relying on its indenting. Perhaps I should set it to always use spaces?

Comment: Yes, always use spaces or at least set tabs and spaces to be visible, so that you can quickly spot the problem.

Comment: @Squeegy: Oh, really? I was quite getting used to it. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: Not deprecated, just discouraged: https://twitter.com/#!/jashkenas/status/134461564165177345