# Coffeescript generating js with jquery ajax call outside document ready function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Can anyone tell me why this coffee script:

```
$ ->  
  $('#btnLogin').live 'click', ->
    $.ajax
      url: 'user/login'
      type: 'POST'
      data: 'Username=' + $('#username').val() + '&password=' + $('#password').val()
      success: (data, status, request) ->
        alert data
```

Generates this javascript with the ajax call outside the document ready method?

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('#btnLogin').live('click', function() {});
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'user/login',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'Username=' + $('#username').val() + '&password=' + $('#password').val(),
    success: function(data, status, request) {
      return alert(data);
    }
  });
}).call(this);
```

Comment: Works on the coffeescript page - see [this](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:%24%20-%3E%20%20%0A%20%20%24('%23btnLogin').live%20'click'%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24.ajax%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20'user%2Flogin'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'POST'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20'Username%3D'%20%2B%20%24('%23username').val()%20%2B%20'%26password%3D'%20%2B%20%24('%23password').val()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20success%3A%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20request)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20data). Are you using newest version?

Comment: when I copied in my code from my source file I realised the IDE was using tabs when I went onto a newline so it was screwing up the formatting, causing this issue. thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple lines in a Coffeescript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991370/multiple-lines-in-a-coffeescript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a problem with tab spacing in visual studio, I changed the tab spacing while I was working on the file and it ballsed everything up. I just deleted all the spacing and tabbed in on every line and then it generated the js I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I you aren't familiar with the site: http://js2coffee.org/ It's a great resource for testing out these issues.  You can convert code between coffeescript from javascript very easily.  I use it often when I run into these issues.